# Ransomware protection

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, duplicati

I am setting up a cheap and easy backup whereby I map an AWS Bucket as a mapped drive and then backup my data to this mapped drive using Duplicati.

What I am wondering, is if I am crypto'd would this also crypto the data in this mapped drive/bucket?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: "Crypto'd" meaning ransomware.

Comment: By "crypto'd", what do you mean? Do you mean if you are hit by ransomware?

Comment: @Randomhero Hi yeah, that is what I meant. My apologies should have been more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Likely yes.  If the ransomware software can access the share, then the data on the share is at risk.  This is why "push" backups are inherently insecure, because the client being backed up *by necessity* has write access on the backup server/backup store.  IMO, the best protection against ransomware is a ZFS-based NAS with a frequent and regular snapshot schedule, such as [FreeNAS](https://www.freenas.org/).